# Converting tomcat logs to CSV using sed

Tags: csv, logging, awk, sed, scripting

I have some application log data on a Linux server, which looks like this:

```
Jan 11 14:24:42 AttackSimulator.abcd [1587566256,49294,"ryan.wright@abcd.com",3237159933,1,0,0,3,"2314","https",443,2899903330,"https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pagead/ads",0,"","","","","1 - Default Policy","","googleads.g.doubleclick.net","GET",4,0,5]
Jan 11 14:24:42 AttackSimulator.abcd [1587566256,49294,"melisa.zeunert@abcd.com",3237159933,1,0,0,3,"2339,37788","http",80,387803624,"http://ping.citrix.com",0,"","","","","3 - Extended Policy High","","ping.citrix.com","HEAD",3,0,4]
```

I want to output this in a CSV file. Everything between the [ ] should be part of the CSV with column names such as DateandTime, AccountID, UserID, ClientIP etc. Something that looks like this:

```
DateandTime, AccountID, UserID, ClientIP
1587566256,49294,"ryan.wright@abcd.com",3237159933
1587566256,49294,"melisa.zeunert@abcd.com",3237159933
```

(This is just an example with only 4 columns. Actual output would have 25)

Any input would be helpful

Comment: Please add to your question (no comment): What have you searched for, and what did you find? What have you tried, and how did it fail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed 's/.*\[\(.*\)]/\1/;1iDateandTime, AccountID, UserID, ClientIP ' file
DateandTime, AccountID, UserID, ClientIP
1587566256,49294,"ryan.wright@scnx.com",3237159933,1,0,0,3,"2314","https",443,2899903330,"https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pagead/ads",0,"","","","","1 - Default Policy","","googleads.g.doubleclick.net","GET",4,0,5
1587566256,49294,"melisa.zeunert@scnx.com",3237159933,1,0,0,3,"2339,37788","http",80,387803624,"http://ping.citrix.com",0,"","","","","3 - Extended Policy High","","ping.citrix.com","HEAD",3,0,4
```

`.*\[` - Exclude everything up to the last `[` square bracket.

`\(.*\)]`  - Include everything within the parenthesis up to the last `]` square bracket

`\1` - Return with back reference the contents stored inside the parenthesis

`1i` - Insert on line 1